# Understanding Leverage Score Sampling to get representative sample

Tags: sampling, svd, matrix-decomposition

I was reading about Leverage Score Sampling. If I am not wrong then what I know that Leverage Score Sampling help us to select representative sample. But I didn't understand how the whole process is done.

I read [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/dwoodruf/www/teaching/15859-fall17/scribe8.pdf) but could not get the whole picture, like how Matrix Chernoff Bound helps to obtain a subspace embedding matrix by leverage scoring. Suppose, I have a million features with million rows then how does Leverage Score Sampling help to get the representative samples? Besides, chatgpt provides,

> Leverage scores can be calculated as the diagonal elements of the hat matrix in a linear regression analysis. The hat matrix represents the linear transformation that maps the response variables to their fitted values, and its diagonal elements are the leverage scores for each data point.
> Leverage scores can be calculated as the diagonal elements of the hat matrix in a linear regression analysis. The hat matrix represents the linear transformation that maps the response variables to their fitted values, and its diagonal elements are the leverage scores for each data point. The hat matrix is defined as $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$, where $X$ is the design matrix for the regression model and $(X'X)^{-1}$ is the inverse of the $X'X$ matrix. The leverage score for each data point $i$ is given by $h_{ii} = H_{ii}$.
> Leverage scores range from $0$ to $1$, with values close to $1$ indicating high leverage and values close to $0$ indicating low leverage. Points with high leverage scores have the potential to have a large impact on the regression model, as they are far away from the average pattern in the data. On the other hand, points with low leverage scores are close to the average pattern and have less influence on the regression model.
> In general, a threshold value of $2k/n$ is commonly used, where $k$ is the number of predictors in the regression model and n is the sample size. This threshold value corresponds to Cook's distance, which is a measure of the impact that each data point has on the regression model. Points with Cook's distance greater than this threshold are considered to have high leverage and are more likely to be included in the sample.

if I understand what it saying then the goal is to identify a small subset of the data that can be used to represent the entire dataset, thereby reducing the computational cost of regression analysis. Points with high leverage scores are more influential and are more likely to be selected for the sample.

**Question:** But as it mentioned threshold value of $2k/n$ is commonly used then isn't the selection process is deterministic and everytime produce the same selection?

It will be a great help if anyone redirect me any resources, papers where I can get the details with some coding explanation side along.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm just a graduate student who has just started reading about this topic either and has proven to get things wrong the first time. So may don't put to much on what I say. But since you ask for references, my answer can may can be of any help.

I don't know where the quoted text is from, but I think we mixing two viewpoints here.

The quoted text wants to use leverage scores to quantify the influence of each data point. If the score is high, the data point has a huge influence on the regression model and deleting or perturbating it can change the solution completely.
So one can either (a) assume the the data point with high leverage score is an outlier which arised from wrong measurements and should be excluded from further computations (deterministic method).

Or (b) one assumes that the measurements are right and especially this point should be considered, due to its great influence. This is important when applying randomized data reduction techniques like sampling. If you want to reduce the number of rows, say form $n$ to $k$, you could just draw $k$ row indices from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with replacement (for the independence assumption besides w/o replacement would make more sense). This is *uniform sampling*, i.e. every row has probability $1/n$ to be drawn in one trial. This approach surely doesn't incorporate the different influence of each row.

A more sophisticated approach is to calculate the statistical leverage scores and then choose $k$ times the $i$-th row with the so-called *importance sampling probability* $p_i = \ell_i/n$ and then rescale the row by an appropriate factor. So an, in terms of leverage scores, influential row has a much higher probability to be included in the sample. This is what the matrix $S_L$ does in your linked lecture notes. They then proceed to show with Chernoff that $S_L$ is embedding the data in a, lets lay simplified, appropriate subspace which doesn't perturbuate the solution "too much".

Unfortunately naively implemented the computation of the leverage scores for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ takes $O(nm^2)$ and thus is not faster than solving for example a overconstrained least-square problem by classic methods like QR/ SVD/ normal equation CG.
Thus one want to approximate the leverage scores or reduce the so-called coherence of the matrix.

References:

1. Introduction to importance sampling : https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5557
2. approximate leverage scores: https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3843
3. more randomized LS approaches : https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08880
4. extensive intro: [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/Book2.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enickhar/Book2.pdf)

I only included resources which I think are suited for a first reading at graduate level and not the important work of these who came up with the ideas. Just ask if you need more references.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DuncanIdaho. It means a lot. I will go through your resources and ask your further question if needed. Thanks again.